# add key and values of array A to array B in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, key

I have these two arrays of objects:

```
A = [
{a: 'john', b: 'joe', c: 'jack'},
{a: 'ben', b: 'alex', c: 'nicole'},
{a: 'sarah', b: 'megan', c: 'bill'}
]
B = [
{x: 'texas', y: 'cali', z: 'washington'},
{x: 'omaha', y: 'hawaii', z: 'york'},
{x: 'michigan', y: 'dakota', z: 'alabama'}
]
```

I want to merge their object values together so I have something like this:

```
C = [
{a: 'john', b: 'joe', c: 'jack', x: 'texas', y: 'cali', z: 'washington'},
{a: 'ben', b: 'alex', c: 'nicole', x: 'omaha', y: 'hawaii', z: 'york'},
{a: 'sarah', b: 'megan', c: 'bill', x: 'michigan', y: 'dakota', z: 'alabama'}
]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var C = A.map((x, i) => Object.assign(x, B[i]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var mergeArray = (A, B) => {
    const res = []
    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++ ) {
        res.push({...A[i], ...B[i]})
    }
    return res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and spread (...) operator

```js
A = [
  { a: "john", b: "joe", c: "jack" },
  { a: "ben", b: "alex", c: "nicole" },
  { a: "sarah", b: "megan", c: "bill" },
];
B = [
  { x: "texas", y: "cali", z: "washington" },
  { x: "omaha", y: "hawaii", z: "york" },
  { x: "michigan", y: "dakota", z: "alabama" },
];

C = A.map((obj, i) => ({ ...obj, ...B[i] }));

console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let C = [];
for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
    C.push(A[i]);
    Object.assign(C[i], B[i]);      
}
console.log(C)
```